# Backup MySQL Server on Git

Tags: database, git, backup

I made some quite unfortunate experiences regarding development of apps with local dev databases. When structural changes to the DB occured and someone did not make a dump in advance the whole thing got messy.

Is there a way to link git to mysqldump to dump the current version into the project folder on a commit automatically? The database currently only has 16 Entries and 8 Tables so the amount of data should not be too high on each commit.

Comment: Wouldnt a migration package for your project language be a better idea? For php you have https://github.com/cakephp/phinx for example.

Comment: I have not considered that, thats why I was asking :^) . I will take a look at it